# jwrapper Install and encryption issues

Tags: jwrapper

we just started playing with jwrapper and we have couple of questions .

1)Is it possible to install the application in the same directory where we click on the installer instead of installing in APPData/Roaming folder .

2) Is it possible to delete all the data automatically once the application is closed ?

3) We are also looking for encryption and want to play around . How can we test it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Its not possible to change the install dir that JWrapper uses.  The reason why is explained here under 'Why can't I change the master folder?':

http://www.jwrapper.com/faq.html

2) If you wanted it to be reliable you might need to launch another virtual app which then communicated with your app and launched an uninstall of your app bundle when your original app had completed.

When you launch your child virtual app JWrapper can handle the communications between them for you:

http://www.jwrapper.com/blog/archives/08-2013

Then when the first app goes down you can use the JWrapper APIs to uninstall the entire bundle:

http://simple-help.com/media/static/jwrapper/jwutils/JWUninstallApp.html#doUninstallOfEntireBundle(boolean)

3) You can email us for a trial license for JWCrypt.  Using it is very simple, the following guide explains how (bottom of the page):

http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-jwcrypt-code-protection.html